# Find the place where application crashed

Tags: java, android, error-handling

How to find out line of code where application failed in Android? (without debugging just to see crash dump)

Comment: doing it without debugging's going to be difficult

Answer (score 4):

See http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html

adb logcat

Answer (score 1):

If it's on a customers device the best way is to install a log collecting app on their phone and have them send you the log.

This is like running adb logcat on their device.

Answer (score 0):

When your application stops unexpectedly, you can go to LogCat and see at which point of line your application has problem.

It will be in redline With Tag

```
CausedBy...Exception then Lineno.
```